# CodeceptJS closing browser window after finish

Tags: testing, automated-tests, puppeteer, codeceptjs

I´m new to `CodeceptJS` with `Puppeteer`. I want to let my window browser open after the finish.

```
Feature('Login');

Scenario('test', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('https://google.es')

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put pause() as the last line of the Testcase

```
Feature('Login');

Scenario('test', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('https://google.es')
    pause(); 

});
```